# Java- Iniciar propiedades generales para los componentes

Tags: java

Buenas tardes. Mi pregunta trata de como generar varias propiedades para un componente(por ejemplo un JLabel)  y poder asignarselo de golpe a todos los JLabel que instanciemos.

Siempre que instaciamos un JLabel realizamos los siguientes pasos.

```
JLabel ejemploLb = new JLabel();
    ejemploLb.setText("LISTADO DE MIEMBROS");
    ejemploLb.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 18));
    ejemploLb.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Y así sucesivamente cada vez que iniciamos un JLabel, con esto quiero preguntar, ¿Existe la posibilidad de poder coger las propiedades de dicho componente(JLabel) y aplicarselo a otro JLabel sin tener que escribir de nuevo las mismas líneas?

Se me ha ocurrido una idea pero me gustaría buscar otra mas sencilla.
Éste es mi ejemplo.

```
/*Instanciamos los componentes*/
     titleLb = new JLabel("LISTADO DE CLIENTES");
     titleL2b = new JLabel("LISTADO DE PROVEEDORES");

/*Llamamos al método y mandamos el JLabel*/
     initJLabel(titleLb);
     initJLabel(titleLb2);

/*En el método introducimos las propiedades que queremos para los JLabel*/
private void initJLabel(JLabel label){    
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 18));
    label.setBackground(Color.red);
}
```

¿Conoceis una manera más sencilla? Muchas gracias por todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que hagas tu propia clase extendida de JLabel y setees esos valores por defecto haciendo `@Override` de los metodos, asi tus objetos seran de tu clase particular con todas las propiedades y eventos que JLabel tiene.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta

> ¿Existe la posibilidad de poder coger las propiedades de dicho componente(JLabel) y aplicarselo a otro JLabel sin tener que escribir de nuevo las mismas líneas?

La respuesta es no, recuerda que cada objeto que creas JLabel es unico y tiene sus propiedades definidas.

Otra forma, es tener un arreglo de JLabels y recorrerlos uno a uno y setear estas propiedades...

```
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[3];

for (int i = 0 i < cur.length; i++){
    labels[i] = new JLabel( cur[i] );
    labels[i].setText("LISTADO DE MIEMBROS");
    ....
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, la idea de hacer una clase extendida es buena pero la duda es ¿Si tengo varios JLabel y cada uno necesita propiedades distintas(por ejemplo: distinto tamaño de letra) me serviría también o la propiedad sería igual para todos?.

Comment: Me imaginaba algo asi y creo que si tienes muchos JLabel y todos tienen distintas propiedades es muy dificil unificar en una clase muchas opciones, no se si podrias tener esas "varias opciones" como limitadas, me explico : los Jlabel pueden ser 1)Letra roja, 2)letra negra y 3)letra verde.. si fuese asi tu caso, creo que podrias inventar la manera de al set, enviarle un valor por ejemplo 1 y definir que para ese 1 el color es rojo, si es 2, es verde y asi, pero como te digo si tus objetos son muy particulares es mejor crearlos 1 por 1

Comment: Me he creado una clase que se llama PropiedadesComponentes donde a cada método le instancio unas propiedades según lo que necesito y desde la clase principal instancio el JLabel  y llamo al método específico para asignarle las propiedades que quiero para dicho JLabel.

Comment: Es como una especia de CSS que se usa en WEB, antiguamente trabajaba en WEB y me aclaraba así para las propiedades pero en JAVA aun me cuesta entender cual es la manera mas óptima o correcta para controlar las propiedades de los componentes y no tener que estar repitiendo tanto código...

Comment: Claro!, puede que nos podamos referir a esto como una clase css pero solo en cuanto a visual, ya que tu clase extendida es algo mas abstracto que eso!